# jqGrid horizontal scrollbar issue in Google chrome

Tags: jqgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jqGrid does not render correctly in Chrome/Chrome Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame)

I have the latest Google Chrome 19 installed.
All the jqGrid [demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), that I see on Google Chrome has a horizontal scrollbar. In Mozilla Firefox it works fine.

Any idea what can be the issue. Any pointers to fix the same.

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame

Comment: Right, this is an exact duplicate of that question... please see it for the solution, too!