# jqGrid - scroll bars on zoom out

Tags: jqgrid, horizontal-scrolling

Recently came through a problem, that is jqGrid is having a horizontal scroll bar in chrome, I have fixed this issue with the help of @Oleg comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame/10621951#comment14519782_10621951)
My application is working fine now... Well
But now if I open my application in laptop, grids are having the horizontal scroll bar. I am able to reproduce this issue by Zoom-out on browser(**Ctrl** + **minus symbol**). But I don't know how to fix this.

Finally what I am trying to say is, Whenever I am zoom-out the application in browser, Grids are showing horizontal scroll bar. I tried `autowidth: true` but not working. Can any one help me on fixing this.

Comment: I notice this happens for me as well, if I go to the jqGrid demo page and zoom out more than one level - although this seems to affect other browsers as well. You might want to [report it](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues) as a jqGrid bug.

Comment: You can try to increase the width of the grid a little (+1px for example). I hope it will solve the problem in the most cases, but the really solution will be more complex: one should change the [ui.jqgrid.css](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css) to use `em` instead of `px` in the most cases. Currently one finds  `font-size:11px` and many values like `height:22px`, `height:17px` and so on. I think that the usage of `em` would allows to implement clear zoom in/zoom out functionality in jqGrid.

Comment: Hai @Oleg, thank you for your reply... I tried both increase grid width and change `px` into `em`. However both are not working for me.