# JqueryGrid does not render correctly in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Currently I am using Chrome v20.0.1132.47 and jqGrid plugin v4.3.1

The problem is the grid width size smaller in Chrome and Safari Browser.

And I am try to make some changes on my jqGrid plugin, where the places are:

1) at the definition of the `isSafari`
   2) inside of `showHideCol`
   3) inside of `setGridWidth`

based on the post [jqGrid does not render correctly in Chrome/Chrome Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame). But unfortunately is not working. So please let me know where i need to change my plugin?

**Updated1:** I make changes my jqGrid plugin Line, `parseFloat($.browser.version)<536.11`  instead of `parseFloat($.browser.version)<536.5` Now its working my Chrome browser. But still now not working in Safari v5.1.2(7534.52.7).

Thanks

Comment: What version of jqGrid are you using? You might want to try upgrading to the latest release, if possible.

Comment: jqgrid 4.3.3 has a bug fix for Chrome.

Comment: Yes, so it is an important upgrade...

Comment: @JustinEthier- same plugin working for me in Chrome browser, but Safari browser is not working. Can you clear me if i want to upgrading the latest plugin? then only to resolve the issue in Safari browser?