# jqGrids in multiple jQuery-UI Tabs inside a jQuery-UI Dialog is causing page's horizontal scroll bar to appear

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple search form which launches a jQuery UI dialog that contains 5 jQuery UI tabs each containing their own jqgrid. Removing the javascript that renders the grids causes the scrollbar to go away. Changing the widths of the grids has no effect.

As you can see from the screen shot the horizontal scroll bar appears and this causes the vertical scroll bar to appear.

I am using jquery 1.7.2, jqueryui 1.8.22, jqgrid 4.4.0 and internet explorer 8.0

[image: Grrr]

I load the dialog by ajax like so

```
    function LoadDialog(id) {
        $('#myPopup').dialog({
            height: 800,
            width: 1100,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#myPopup').html('');
                $.ajax(
                    '<%: Url.Action("loadDetails") %>/' + id,
                    {
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#myPopup').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            DisplayMessage(textStatus, errorThrown);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
        $('#myPopup').dialog('open');
    }
```

The loadDetails action method returns this view

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="details"></div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("tab1") %></li>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("tab2") %></li>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("tab3") %></li>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("tab4") %></li>
            <li><%: Html.ActionLink("tab5") %></li>
    </div>
<div>
```

With this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tabs').tabs({
    cache: true,
    ajaxOptions: {
        cache: true
    }
});
</script>
```

Each tab loads up a table and a div for the jqgrid with the appropriate javascript to load the grid, their widths are set to 1000px.

```
<table id="gridtableX'></table><div id="griddivX"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#gridtableX').jqGrid({
    url: '/Home/GetGridData/1234',
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 320,
    colNames: ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'Col1',width:30,sortable:false},
        {name:'Col2',width:40,sortable:false}, 
        {name:'Col3',width:40,sortable:false}, 
        {name:'Col4',width:40,sortable:false}],
    rowNum:4,
    width:1000,
    scrollOffset:0,
    hidegrid: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    hoverrows: false,
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e){ return false; },
    pager: '#griddivX'}).navGrid('#griddivX',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
</script>
```

I'm currently working on a simple example, but it's taking a while.
If someone has run into this before, please let me know.
What is causing this, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting problem! Could you post URL which can be used to examine the problem?

I suppose, that the reason of the problem could be [cellWidth](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.0/js/grid.base.js#L184-191) function introduced in jqGrid 4.4.0. Just for testing of that you can modify the code of `cellWidth` and include the line

```js
if ($.browser.msie) { return false; }
```

somewhere at the beginning of the code of `cellWidth`. In the case no div having 10000px as `left:10000px` will be created. Alternatively you can try to use to modify `left:10000px` to `left:-10000px` or to make some other experiments. Additionally I would recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621951/315935) which was the origin of the introduction of `cellWidth` function.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. Do you tried to use `left:-1000px`? Probably one could add additional style `position: "absolute"`: `style='position: absolute; left:-1000px; top: -1000px'`

Comment: Hmm, I left the line `if ($.browser.msie) { return false; }` in the cellWidth function, however I see now that that does not completely fix the issue as when I close a dialog the blocking div gets resized to larger than the screen. Looks like I'm going to have to read your full answer on your link. Looks good though!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Oleg's answer I was able to solve the issue.
For easier maintenance I added a new javascript file to my project and include it after my `jquery.jgGrid.js`

```
$.jgrid.cellWidth = function () {
    var $testDiv = $("<div class='ui-jqgrid' style='position:absolute;left:-1000px;top:-1000px'><table class='ui-jqgrid-btable' style='width:5px;'><tr class='jqgrow'><td style='width:5px;'></td></tr></table></div>"),
    testCell = $testDiv.appendTo("body")
        .find("td")
        .width();
    $testDiv.remove();
    return 5 !== testCell;
}
```