# jqgrid horizontal scrollbar issue in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

in my jqgrid (using version 4.2.0), using Chrome and Safari appears horizontal scrollbar. I change the css like this:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
position: relative;
margin: 0em;
padding: 0;
    //overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
text-align: left;
```

}

it works on Safari. Also it works in Chrome but last column it's truncated, and if i resize the page the last column disappear. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of horizontal scrollbar are wrong calculation of the width of grid in jqGrid of the old version which you use. All jqGrid versions < 4.3.3 has the problem. I recommend you to update jqGrid to the current version. Alternatively you can modify `jquery.jqGrid.src` of the version which you use in one of the way described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621951/315935). You can get minimized version `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` from `jquery.jqGrid.src` using any minimizer which you like. For example [Microsoft Ajax Minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/), [UglifyJS2](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) or [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).