# JQGrid - Frozen column - ondblClickRow event not firing on frozen columns

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

Jqgrid displaying frozen column successfully, but ondblClickRow event not firing for frozen columns. Its working fine for non-frozen columns. please help for this.

I am declaring frozen columns as per below.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("destroyFrozenColumns").jqGrid("setColProp", "ID", { frozen: true }).jqGrid("setColProp", "Name", { frozen: true }).jqGrid("setFrozenColumns").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
```

Am i missing something here for ondblClickRow event for frozen columns?

Comment: Which version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you use? I tried the current 4.13.3 (and 4.13.4-pre) and `ondblClickRow` worked without any problems on my demo.

Comment: Then you use wrong tag ["free-jqgrid"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info). The version 4.4.4 is very old and it's dead. You can use free jqGrid 4.13.3 loading all the files from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If you use it from NuGet, then you should uninstall the old one and install it from [another NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/). Free jqGrid contains a lot of improvements in the implementation of frozen columns.

Comment: Thanks you..I checked with new version, ondblClickRow working now. but now facing another problem. If at page load, No records from DB then grid displays "No records to display" but when I increase my date range and click on get data button, data binds but no horizontal scroll at all...

Comment: You are welcome! One should distinguish different problems. Frozen columns feature is very restricted in old version 4.4.4 (3.5 years old) and it's very buggy. About another problems: I try to hold free jqGrid compatible with old 4.x versions of jqGrid. It could be still some minor compatibility problems because many parts of the old code are full rewritten. You should post the JavaScript code, which you use and the demo data (2-3 roes of demo data), which can be used to reproduce your problem. Alternatively you can post URL to the demo.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, this line was the problem..  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("clearGridData"); I have replaced it with jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("GridUnload");  and everything working fine...I got this line from your other answers...thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome! I still recommend you to migrate from the dead retro version 4.4.4 to free jqGrid 4.13.3. [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10621951/315935) describes an old problem in Chrome after one update of the Chrome browser. The problem is fixed in 4.3.3, but a close problem can appears every day. It's dangerous to use the product (the version) which is not supported since a long period of time.