# jqGrid doe not render correctly in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jqgrid

Its basically same problem as here [jqGrid does not render correctly in Chrome/Chrome Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588587/jqgrid-does-not-render-correctly-in-chrome-chrome-frame) , bu the same solution does not work for me. I have Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and JqGrid version 4.7.1.

THe $.browser .... lines do not exsist in the jqGrid code anymore. How can I fix this problem now. (And no i can not update my jqGrid version).

This is what it looks like. I blanked out the text on the table. And in firefox this problem does not exsist.

[image]
Image with some data rows. As seen filter row is still broken.
[image]

Comment: The choice of retro version 4.7.1 is very strange. It's already **commercial** Guriddo and it has new license and it can't be used for free (see the price [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). The last jqGrid version is 4.7. Later there are two main alternative forks: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) (the current version 4.14.0) and [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) (the current version 5.2.0). About your main problem: you should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem or at least post JavaScript code.

Comment: This line in the older jqGrid version "isSafari = $.browser.webkit || $.browser.safari ? true : false;" Caused the same problem. This is a issue between jqGrid and Chrome. THe link i added also suggest a solution, this isSafari variable is not present in jqGrid version 4.7.1. Updatind jqGrid is quite difficult because of the type of client + we have our own code dependant on jqGrid 4.7.1.

Comment: You should forget very old versions <4.3.3 which had the line `isSafari = $.browser.webkit || $.browser.safari ? true : false;`. The calculation of the width of columns is changed since a long time. Instead of that you should provide details about you code. The picture, which you post have no horizontal scrollbar, but it has no rows with the data.

Comment: It's important to understand, that version 4.7.1 is **dead**. You should understand that it's not supported. It means, that if you find a bug in the version, then it will be not fixed. You will have to fix it yourself. If I understand correctly your problem, then it's not exist in the current [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop. You can test it by temporary changing the URLs from which you load jqGrid files (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: jqGrid is statically packed into the entire project. Changing the jqGrid version is not that simple. Ou client has really strict rules. This version was taken i dont know when and it is there now and changing it will be a headache. The problem is with the column filter line. The empty boxes partly go under the edge. Getting the code to show is headache also. Code is spread between 10+ files.

Comment: All what you explain are *your* problems. The version 4.7.1 will still stay dead and will be not changed. Even if you will fix the bug yourself then you will have to update the copy of the fixed version on all 10+ files, which you have. Typically one use some build system (grunt, gulp and so on). One make changes of one file, rebuild the site and all copies will be updated. By the way, all current web browsers use HTTP/2 and thus it's better **not concatenate** many files in one file. The best practice is loading the files from CDN, which support HTTP/2.

Comment: Do you tested, whether your problem exist in free jqGrid 4.14.0? To make the test you need to change maximally 3 lines of your HTML code.

Comment: To test it in this project, i need to download the freeJqGrid.src.js. Then in buildconfigs i need to remove old jqGrid and add new. And then i need to hope that the code we have built on top of jqGrid wont break.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you. Why you explain me about your internal problems. You use **commercial** version 4.7.1 of Guriddo jqGrid and even the old one. I develop *alternative* fork under the name "free jqGrid", which everybody can use completely free of charge. All your comments about your internal problems sound like the following: You came to BMW repair service and you explain that you have some problems with your old retro Mercedes car. Moreover you expect that BMW repairs your old car for free. Which reaction you expect from BMW?

Comment: @Oleg I tested freejQuery, it broke most of the pages, and the ones that werent broken were even worse than before. Additionally, i dont have the autority to issue such large scale change in the project(it is actually lot of work to fix everything). So im stuck with the dead version of jqGrid.

Comment: Im willing to fix it myself, i just need to know what might be the cause of the problem and where can i find the piece of code responsible for it.

Comment: I can't help you in any way if I don't examine the demo, which reproduce the problem. About your tests with free jqGrid: I suppose that you did the test incorrectly (for example, you used mix between old CSS and new JS). In any way, one can go forward only having some demos. If you say that free jqGrid have some compatibility problem - you should provide the demo, which demonstrates the problem. If you have some other problem - you should provide the corresponding demo. All other common discussions is pure spending our time.

Comment: Problem with the demo. I dont know how to use jsFIddle, i have never gotten anything to work in there. Hmm... but i think i have found the location where i can fix it. How can i change ui-search-toolbar height?

Comment: Nobody will do your job. If you search in Google for videos "jsFIddle how to use" you will find many videos. Look one from them and 5 min later you will know the basis of jqFiddle. Alternatively you can get one from my old jsdiddle demos, fork it, modify it, save and you will have your demo. Try https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3ddnkvow/, https://jsfiddle.net/vwgd1ruf/ or https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/