# overflow:auto in jqgrid not working after upgrading jquery from 1.6.2 to 3.2.1

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

This is my code.

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0em;
    padding:0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:left;
}
```

But scroll bar is not shown in my page. Can any one help,
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should always write **which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover, it could be imprtant to know, which CSS framework you use (jQuery UI or Bootstrap or both) and in which version. I develop free jqGrid fork and it's compatible to jQuery 3.2.1. The CSS setting, which you use are default (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L359-L366)) and work.

Comment: I am using jquery3.2.1 , jqGrid version 4.1.1 . CSS framework is jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

The version 4.1.1 is almost 6 years old. The version is dead since many years. It's not compatible to jQuery 3.2.1 and to current versions of web browsers. For example, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621951/315935) describes problems in jqGrid in versions less as 4.3.3 in Chrome 19 and higher.

I strictly recommend you to upgrade to the current version (4.14.0) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and the problem should be solved.

Comment: Thank you, I will try with latest version and check

Comment: but after upgrading jqgrid, CSS is not been applied to my grid, Can you help in resolving this issue

Comment: @teja: You should provide **the demo**, which reproduce your problem. I'm sure that you use jqGrid in the wrong way, but I can't guess, which error you use. Look at [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) for code examples.